# converting .csv files to midi

Tags: midi

my question is related to [How to decode this CSV from a MIDI file?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/24893/how-to-decode-this-csv-from-a-midi-file#new-answer?newreg=a281261a4ba2486a81eb5facbb27ec16), which covers converting .csv to .mid and vice versa.  I'm using csvmidi.exe (http://www.fourmilab.ch/webtools/midicsv), and, to my knowledge, that's the only option for converting .csv to .mid.  My problem is that I can't get it to work, and I suspect it's something to do with how I'm formatting my .csv files.  Walker has this example on the website:

```
0, 0, Header, 1, 2, 480
1, 0, Start_track
1, 0, Title_t, "Close Encounters"
1, 0, Text_t, "Sample for MIDIcsv Distribution"
1, 0, Copyright_t, "This file is in the public domain"
1, 0, Time_signature, 4, 2, 24, 8
1, 0, Tempo, 500000
1, 0, End_track
2, 0, Start_track
2, 0, Instrument_name_t, "Church Organ"
2, 0, Program_c, 1, 19
2, 0, Note_on_c, 1, 79, 81
2, 960, Note_off_c, 1, 79, 0
2, 960, Note_on_c, 1, 81, 81
2, 1920, Note_off_c, 1, 81, 0
2, 1920, Note_on_c, 1, 77, 81
2, 2880, Note_off_c, 1, 77, 0
2, 2880, Note_on_c, 1, 65, 81
2, 3840, Note_off_c, 1, 65, 0
2, 3840, Note_on_c, 1, 72, 81
2, 4800, Note_off_c, 1, 72, 0
2, 4800, End_track
0, 0, End_of_file
```

And I can't even get that to work.  I've tried pasting it into Notepad and saving as .csv, pasting into Excel and saving as .csv, and I'm not sure what the other options are.

Another possibility is that I'm not putting the right command into csvmidi.exe when it opens (I'm not familiar with that language).  Right now I'm putting in (exactly):

```
csvmidi -u -v "sample.csv" "sample111.mid"
```

and have also tried these:

```
csvmidi -v "sample.csv" "sample111.mid"
csvmidi -u "sample.csv" "sample111.mid"
csvmidi "sample.csv" "sample111.mid"
csvmidi sample.csv sample111.mid
```

but I always get the same error (no matter which of the above I try):

```
csvmidi: Error on line 1:
  csvmidi -u -v "sample.csv" "sample111.mid"
  Missing absolute time (field 2).
```

but I'm certain I have a number in the time slot of each event.

Any help would be much appreciated - thanks!

*****Update 10-28-2018

The .csv files I'm using can be found here:

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1SG9rV47dGpM6_VrTOoA4k4Oq55cacm3B
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1GOMvhB9s00al3CiTa0v0a_w3fSS3X4Ch

Comment: Upload the CSV file somewhere, or show a hexdump of the beginning of the CSV file.

Comment: `sample_from_website` works. With `my_example`, it complains that the events are out of order. (But I've run the Linux version of `csvmidi`.)

Comment: Thanks!  I still can't get it to work though.  Do you just open csvmidi.exe and paste this into the console:

Comment: csvmidi "sample_from_website.csv" "temp.mid"

Comment: And hit enter?  When I hit enter nothing happens.  If I hit enter again, it given me the error in original post.

Comment: If nothing happens, then it waits to read its input (an empty line is not valid input), and this means that it did not process the file name. Try without quotes, or `csvmidi < sample_from_website.csv > temp.mid`.

Comment: I figured it out - it was because I was pasting my commands into the csvmidi.exe window that opens when you click on the icon.  Instead I should have been putting the commands into my actual Windows command (cmd) line.  All good now - thanks so much for your help and quick responses.

Comment: Please create an answer.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out - it was because I was pasting my commands into the csvmidi.exe window that opens when you click on the icon. Instead I should have been putting the commands into my actual Windows command (cmd) line.